# Array push and pop operations - are they atomic?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Are Array push and pop operation atomic?

I have a webworker that is listening for messages and updates an Array and
I am wondering if the `arr.length === 0` will always return a correct answer?

Comment: Updates an array in the worker's context?

Comment: While a webworker can span an additional thread for its work, the worker itself is again singlethreaded. And when you pass your data between main thread and worker via `postMessage` the data is *copied*  and not shared.